# What happened to "Is initial view controller"checkbox?

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta5

I just added a second view controller to my project, but when I went to set is as the **initial view controller**, the very convenient **checkbox was missing** (the Title label is also missing). I embedded it into a navigation controller just to see what was up, and the checkbox was available for the nav controller. We used to be able to have a project with two view controllers, no nav controller, and be able to simply check the box to set which was the initial. **Is this a bug or a deliberate move away from the checkbox in anything that's not a navigation controller?**

---

**View controller (no checkbox):**

[image]

---

**Navigation controller:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Inspector's contents look a lot like you have selected the view controller's main view, **not** the view controller itself.

Comment: Embarrassing. Good catch, Thx

Comment: Happens even in the best families :-)

Comment: Lol. They moved that bar (with the exit button, etc) to the bottom. I’ll blame it on that